# Token Record Lifecycle

Tags: doorkeeper

We are using Doorkeeper to handle authentication with a Ruby On Rails API. When I was looking through a database on the server, I noticed that there are a lot of records in the oauth_tokens table, a good number have expired already! To be fair, our tokens expire every 2 hours...but that still will add up for a lot of users over time.

I have looked through the documentation, and the code and am still lost

Is there a way for doorkeeper to automatically delete old, expired access tokens? (I'd prefer a set and forget sort of solution.)